# How to specify a target type for /drawable/*.xml?

Tags: android

I have 2 different "styles" (border width and colour) I want to apply to EditText and ImageView. They suggested me to add them into drawable/my_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       ......>
       <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <stroke ..... />
  <padding .... />
</shape>
```

I wonder, how can I:

```
- create different border width and colour for ImageView and EditText? Should I somehow specify a target type?
- as far as I understand, those "styles" will be applied to ... each control? 
- how can I apply them to a particular EditText or ImageView?
```